# Magento - set discount on a product before the cart

Tags: magento, cart, discount

i'm new on magento and i'm working on a module that permt a user to choose and to have the gfit with the product that he purchase.
my question is, how can i set a discount on specific product in the checkout ? 
i've  used :
i make the modification in the observer  on the event

> checkout_cart_add_product_complete

.

```
$_cart_products = Mage::getModel("checkout/cart") -> getItems();

//foreache...
//if ...

$_cart_product->setDiscountAmount($realPrice-$giftPrice);
$_cart_product->setBaseDiscountAmount($realPrice-$giftPrice);
$_cart_product->save();
```

But it dosen't work 
thank you for your help  :)

Comment: if i use coupon codes, i'll generate a lot for just one use !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to code for doing this,just go to admin and you will see promotion tab,just select this, from here you can define promotion rules for products

Comment: i need it to be completely dynamic, no need to add rules.
the user just specify the gift products and with which product the are associated.